# Why homotopy category is not abelian?

Tags: category-theory, homological-algebra, abelian-categories

Let A denote an abelian category, Ch(A) denote the corresponding category of chain complex. Then let HoCh(A) denote the category whose objects are the same of Ch(A), but the map between objects are equivalent class that identify maps that are homotopic. The result is Ch(A) is an abelian category but HoCh(A) is no longer abelian.

I even do not know how to start? Which condition of abelian category will fail in this case? Maybe some map in the category does not have kernel?

Comment: @Eric: given the homological algebra tag, presumably the homotopy category of chain complexes.

Comment: Related: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/22914/is-the-chain-homotopy-category-kab-an-abelian-category-by-ab-i-mean-the-c

Comment: @EricWofsey Sorry about that, I have edited the question.

Comment: @JohnMa Thanks, actually I have read that but I have not learn triangulated category and do not quite understand that answer......

Comment: For abelian groups, I've posted a [concrete counterexample](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1280199/116766) for $\operatorname{K}(\mathsf{Ab})$ not being abelian.

Comment: @TakumiMurayama I am sorry, actually I do not quite understand your post. Do I need to read Eisenbud's book first?

Comment: @qwwwqq I apologize, the post was written for someone with the book right in front of them. I've edited it accordingly so the statement being proved is clear.